# how to split a string containing numbers in our outside parenthesis using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
535354 345356 3543674 34667 2345347 -3536 4532452 (234536 2345634 -4513453) (2345 -13254 13545)
```

The text between () is always at the end of the string (at least for now).

i need to split it into an array similar to this:

```
[0] => [0] 535354,345356,3543674,34667,2345347,-3536,4532452
[1] => [0] 234536,2345634,-4513453
    => [1] 2345,-13254,13545
```

What expression should i use for preg_match_all?
Best i could get with my limited knowledge is `/([0-9]{1,}){1,}.*(?=(\(.*\)))/U` but i still get some unwanted elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match chunks of numbers outside of parentheses and those inside with `"~(?<=\()\s*$numrx\s*(?=\))|\s*$numrx~"` where a `$numrx` stands for the number regex (that can be enhanced further).

The `-?\d+(?:\s+-?\d+)*`  matches an optional `-`, 1 or more digits, and then 0+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with optional `-` and 1+ digits. `(?<=\()\s*$numrx\s*(?=\))` matches the same only if preceded  with `(` and followed with `)`.

See this PHP snippet:

```
$s = "535354 345356 3543674 34667 2345347 -3536 4532452 (234536 2345634 -4513453) (2345 -13254 13545)";
$numrx = "-?\d+(?:\s+-?\d+)*";
preg_match_all("~(?<=\()\s*$numrx\s*(?=\))|\s*$numrx~", $s, $m);
$res = array();
foreach ($m[0] as $k) {
    array_push($res,explode(" ",trim($k)));
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
[0] => Array                                                                                                                                                     
    (                                                                                                                                                            
        [0] => 535354                                                                                                                                            
        [1] => 345356                                                                                                                                            
        [2] => 3543674                                                                                                                                           
        [3] => 34667                                                                                                                                             
        [4] => 2345347                                                                                                                                           
        [5] => -3536                                                                                                                                             
        [6] => 4532452                                                                                                                                           
    )                                                                                                                                                            

[1] => Array                                                                                                                                                     
    (                                                                                                                                                            
        [0] => 234536  
        [1] => 2345634                                                                                                                                           
        [2] => -4513453                                                                                                                                          
    )                                                                                                                                                            

[2] => Array                                                                                                                                                     
    (                                                                                                                                                            
        [0] => 2345                                                                                                                                              
        [1] => -13254                                                                                                                                            
        [2] => 13545                                                                                                                                             
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
$re = '/\d+(?=[^()]*[()])/';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4MQuD5/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\d+       # match 1 or more digits
(?=       # lookahead start
   [^()]* # match anything but ( or )
   [()]   # match ( or )
)         # lookahead end
```